# Can the 750Ti and HD 5450 be used for mining? What software do you suggest.

Tags: gpu-mining

I am currently mining with an R9 380 and I am trying to expand. I have an 5450 and I think I can get a 750ti for about 30 dollars. What software should work nicely with 750Ti and/or the HD 5450. Does anyone have any idea what kind of hashrate I could get out of the 5450? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mining with any GPU is likely worth it in the long-run if XMR reaches anywhere near prospected market cap.

With that being said, investing $30 in a mid to low-end Gfx card is probably not ideal when you can invest $30 for a top-tier CPU (Opteron 6276), if mining is its purpose.

At current prices and mining difficulty, the latter should amortize within 3 months, while the 750TI in 6. I'm not sure about the HD5450 but it should pay for its electricity even at current prices.

Personally I am mining with a GTX 750 and am getting on average about 200H/s with ccminer and 220H/s with the new xmrMiner, the latter being more optimized but also having a higher impact on performance. A 750TI should push a bit more than that, maybe 240-250 depending on specs and miner.

A HD5450 is very low-end and it shouldn't go much past 50H/s.

Building a dedicated mining machine with $50 using a second-hand Opteron 6276 would probably be twice as good as anything you would be planning with the gfx card update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your operating system. For all mining questions, I would suggest starting with the [Monero mining wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index).

For Windows, there are two options for NVIDIA (ccminer-cryptonight and xmrMiner). The second is much newer.

For CPU, there are many options. The easiest is Monero Spelunker, but the best is probably XMR-STAK-CPU.

I'm not sure what hashrate you can get out of the 5450.